# Get db path which connects with odbc connection

Tags: c#, ms-access, odbc

How i get full path of database(.mdb) in c# which is connected by ODBC connection ?

Desire output:-

`String path="path of ms access file";`

Is there any method or function available in c# to get db location ?

Comment: you mean to say connection string?

Comment: no , in a variable get the path where db is located

Comment: You can't get a path to the DB file, an ODBC connection is an abstraction layer for connecting to a database, the physical file of the database is controlled by the underlying DB engine that you are connecting to.

Comment: My real problem is i have two pc 1 is server and another is client. i need the location of db in client pc on button click. access file on server and both pc is connceted by odbc connection is that possible??

Comment: Not exactly sure of what you're trying to do, but... I have an app, for two different clients, with two separate dbs (MySQL). I connect via odbc, using a dsn file. On my dev machine, I have a popup when I log in (as a developer), which let's me select which db I want to use. All that does is relink the tables using one of two different dsn files. Is that what you're after?

Comment: i only want to know where is my db (ms access file) is located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```csharp
using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(myConnectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    String path = con.Database;
    Console.WriteLine(path);
```

It doesn't just parse the connection string, because when `myConnectionString` is `DSN=db1;` (a System DSN), `path` still contains

```csharp
C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb
```